# HTML5 Dynamically create Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi there I have a question about dynamically creating a canvas using javascript.

I create a canvas like this:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.id     = "CursorLayer";
canvas.width  = 1224;
canvas.height = 768;
canvas.style.zIndex   = 8;
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.border   = "1px solid";
```

but when I try to locate it, I get a `null` value:

```
cursorLayer = document.getElementById("CursorLayer");
```

Am I doing it wrong? Is there a better way to create a canvas using JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add canvas to a page with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152224/add-canvas-to-a-page-with-javascript)

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The problem is that you do not insert your canvas element in the document body.

Just do the following:

```
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

Example:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

canvas.id = "CursorLayer";
canvas.width = 1224;
canvas.height = 768;
canvas.style.zIndex = 8;
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.border = "1px solid";


var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(canvas);

cursorLayer = document.getElementById("CursorLayer");

console.log(cursorLayer);

// below is optional

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)";
ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)";
ctx.fillRect(150, 150, 200, 200);
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)";
ctx.fillRect(200, 50, 200, 200);
```

Comment: how to do that without appending? like document.write to current position?

Comment: how to append canvas to a particular div  $("div").appendChild(canvas)  is that possible

Comment: To clarify, you don't *just* do the following, you still have to create it. The best answers usually include all the info. But yeah.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you call it before DOM has loaded. Firstly, create the element and add atrributes to it, then after DOM has loaded call it. In your case it should look like that:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.id     = "CursorLayer";
canvas.width  = 1224;
canvas.height = 768;
canvas.style.zIndex   = 8;
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.border   = "1px solid";
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("CursorLayer");
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, creating a new element does not trigger window.onload...

Comment: It does not, but you can't call too fast elements after created. Creating element and calling it will return null, but if you wait a bit or add window.onload it will return HTMLElement.

Comment: OK I understand better what your point is. It makes sense in the context of a page being loaded but I tested it in the context of an already loaded page.

Answer (score 1):

Via Jquery:

```
$('<canvas/>', { id: 'mycanvas', height: 500, width: 200});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8DEsJ/736/

Comment: jQuery is as usual unnecessary to do this simple task.

Answer (score 1):

## Alternative

Use element `.innerHTML=` which is [quite fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51140250/860099) in modern browsers

```js
document.body.innerHTML = "<canvas width=500 height=150 id='CursorLayer'>";


// TEST

var ctx = CursorLayer.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
 <script>
  var sun = new Image();
  var moon = new Image();
  var earth = new Image();
  function init() {
  sun.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/1456/Canvas_sun.png';
  moon.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/1443/Canvas_moon.png';
  earth.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/1429/Canvas_earth.png';
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }

  function draw() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)';
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 153, 255, 0.4)';
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(150, 150);

  // Earth
  var time = new Date();
  ctx.rotate(((2 * Math.PI) / 60) * time.getSeconds() + ((2 * Math.PI) / 60000) * 
  time.getMilliseconds());
  ctx.translate(105, 0);
  ctx.fillRect(10, -19, 55, 31); 
  ctx.drawImage(earth, -12, -12);

   // Moon
  ctx.save();
  ctx.rotate(((2 * Math.PI) / 6) * time.getSeconds() + ((2 * Math.PI) / 6000) * 
  time.getMilliseconds());
  ctx.translate(0, 28.5);
  ctx.drawImage(moon, -3.5, -3.5);
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.restore();

   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(150, 150, 105, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
   ctx.stroke();

   ctx.drawImage(sun, 0, 0, 300, 300);

   window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }

   init();
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```