# Why doesn't my function show in html page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I fix this problem ?

```
window.onload=function setup(){

    createCanvas(200,200);
}

window.onload=function draw (){
    background(55);
}
```

I included the javascript file in the html page
 when I run html page does not show my canvas is there a syntax error ?

Comment: `is there a syntax error`  there is, if that's your whole code.  What does createCanvas & background do?

Comment: so should be createElement for new element ?

Comment: Is this your complete code? Do the developer tools (console) show any errors/exceptions?

Comment: This html page <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html> this too js file window.onload = function() {
    createCanvas(200,200);
    background(55);
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two `window.onload` functions. Every time you assign this property it replaces the previous one. When the page loads, only the last one will be called.

You can combine the functions into one:

```
window.onload = function() {
    createCanvas(200,200);
    background(55);
};
```

Or you can use `addEventListener` to add multiple event listeners.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    createCanvas(200, 200);
});
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    background(55);
});
```

Comment: I tried first but doesn't working

Comment: Is it doing the `background(55)`?

Comment: just white page

Comment: doesnt canvas show

Comment: What kind of debugging have you tried? Have you added a breakpoint to the function, or added `console.log` statements?

Comment: This console error Uncaught ReferenceError: createCanvas is not defined
    at window.onload (main.js:2)

Comment: You're trying to call a function that you never defined. Define the `createCanvas` function.

Comment: I wrote this window.onload = function() {
    createCanvas(200,200);
    background(55);
}; and gave this error

Comment: But do you have `function createCanvas(height, width) { ... }` anywhere? You can't call a function that you haven't defined.

Comment: Just there is that codes in js file

Comment: `createCanvas` is not a built-in JavaScript function. So you either need to define it yourself or load a library that defines it.

Comment: like createElement('canvas') and then call this

Comment: @SkyBlue It sounds like you need to do some more research and maybe read some JavaScript tutorials. Here is an example of how to create a canvas element and insert it into the document: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652513/html5-dynamically-create-canvas. You are missing a lot of code.

Comment: Okay thanks for helps