# How to convert p5.JS canvas creation code to HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, p5.js

How would I translate this p5.js code into Canvas? The `createCanvas` method, for example, is not in Canvas. The same goes for `draw()` and `setup()`.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300);
}

function draw() {
  background(50);

  for (var r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
      stroke(0);
      fill(10 * r, 10 * c, 255)
      rect(30, 30, 30, 30);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: are you asking how to access the underlying HTMLCanvas that P5.js uses to draw on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting simple p5 like this is straightforward after checking out a tutorial on basic canvas. That said, p5 is doing a lot under the hood and packing much more functionality into calls like `createCanvas`, so if you find you're just reinventing many of the abstractions it already provides or using advanced features, it's probably best to just use p5.

`rect(30, 30, 30, 30);` just keeps drawing on the same spot over and over, so I assume you wanted `rect(30 * r, 30 * c, 30, 30);`

Also, since you're not animating anything, it's probably best to use p5's [`noLoop`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/noLoop) and skip `requestAnimationFrame` altogether, since it's just burning CPU cycles as it stands here.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = canvas.height = 300;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

(function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(50, 50, 50)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (let r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${10 * r}, ${10 * c}, 255)`;
      ctx.fillRect(30 * r, 30 * c, 30, 30);
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
      ctx.strokeRect(30 * r, 30 * c, 30, 30);
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Libraries like p5.js exist because the native API for Canvas is not particularly user friendly. However if you insist on using Canvas directly you should start with something like [this tutorial on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial).

Specifically regarding the methods used in your example (createCanvas, fill, rect), this [existing StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652513/html5-dynamically-create-canvas) covers all three.