# How to add a html5 CANVAS within a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using the below code to generate a `canvas`.  At the moment it adds the canvas element to the `body`, how can I get it to add it to a `div` named "divGameStage", which is not nested within any other elements, except `body`.

EDIT: I've tried the first suggestion, but no canvas is appearing, full code is as follows:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Game Stage</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadCanvas(id) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        div = document.getElementByID(id); 
        canvas.id     = "CursorLayer";
        canvas.width  = 1224;
        canvas.height = 768;
        canvas.style.zIndex   = 8;
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.border   = "1px solid";
        div.appendChild(canvas)
    }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>The most important heading on this page</h1>
    <p>With some supplementary information</p>
</header>
<div id="divControls"></div>
<div id="divGameStage"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    loadCanvas(divGameStage);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add canvas to a page with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152224/add-canvas-to-a-page-with-javascript)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just try this code and will work for you surely:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Game Stage</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadCanvas(id) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        div = document.getElementById(id); 
        canvas.id     = "CursorLayer";
        canvas.width  = 1224;
        canvas.height = 768;
        canvas.style.zIndex   = 8;
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.border   = "1px solid";
        div.appendChild(canvas)
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>The most important heading on this page</h1>
    <p>With some supplementary information</p>
</header>
<div id="divControls"></div>
<div id="divGameStage"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    loadCanvas("divGameStage");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Some things keep in mind:

- Error No 1 is missing quotes in loadCanvas("divGameStage");
- Error No 2 is syntax error div = document.getElementById(id); "..ID(id)" was in your code.

If then also it doesnt work then i am sure that you are testing it on Internet Explorer `(specially < IE9)`
If these is the case, FYI IE9 and above supports canvas no other lesser version supports canvas

Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I obviously wasn't paying attention to my quotes and case!

Answer (score 4):

You just have to append it to your `<div>` instead of the body:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadCanvas(id) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
            div = document.getElementById(id);
        canvas.id     = "canvGameStage";
        canvas.width  = 1000;
        canvas.height = 768;
        canvas.style.zIndex   = 8;
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.border   = "1px solid";
        div.appendChild(canvas);
    }
    /* ... */
    loadCanvas("divGameStage");
</script>
```

Quite simply :-)

Comment: Thanks, but no canvas has appeared, I've pasted the updated code, am I calling loadCanvas in the wrong place or is it something else?

Comment: when you say not appearing have you checked the source?  I'm pretty sure the canvas wont be visible to you until you draw on it in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadCanvas() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.id     = "canvGameStage";
        canvas.width  = 1000;
        canvas.height = 768;
        canvas.style.zIndex   = 8;
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.border   = "1px solid";
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "divGameStage";
        div.appendChild(canvas);
        document.body.appendChild(div)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem here is this:

```
loadCanvas(divGameStage);
```

Wrap `divGameStage` in quotes:

```
loadCanvas("divGameStage");
```

Since it needs to be a string to be run through `getElementById`.