# Unexpected Identifier syntax error

Tags: javascript, html

I have a syntax error, but am not sure where. I have no typos and ran an alert as a test and it worked. Also I can use my canvas in my html but not in my external javascript.

HTML:

```
<div id="inner">
    </div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('inner').innerHtml='<canvas id="gameCanvas1" width="800px" height="500px" style="display:block;background:#E6E6E6;margin:100px auto 0px;"></canvas>'
```

Comment: `GetElementById`??? It should be `getElementById` like your first one.

Comment: That took care of the error but the canvas still will not display.

Comment: `innerHtml` is a custom property in HTMLElement, JS really is case-sensitive.

Comment: Don't use random case. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML

Comment: To create the canvas object, look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10652513/1267304) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6608996/1267304) posts.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the

```
document.getElementById("inner")
```

at the start of the line and fix the case in the following `GetElementById` (which should be `getElementById`) and in `innerHtml` (which should really be `innerHTML`).

And next time, ensure your code is easy to read to avoid this kind of error. This means for example you can read it without horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your JS as below:

```
document.getElementById("inner").innerHtml='<canvas id="gameCanvas1" width="800px" height="500px" style="display:block;background:#E6E6E6;margin:100px auto 0px;"></canvas>'
```